# Disable stepper driver

Tags: stepper-driver

I'm trying to disable the stepper driver to allow manual operation of the lead screw it's controlling.

I've tried connecting MF+ and MF- to ground and 24V in multiple combinations but the motor was still energized. Any ideas? Thank you.

[image: DM542Y stepper driver]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you driving the other +/- inputs? Drive MF the same.

These inputs are typically meant to be driven with an open collector output. A logic output will usually work also if VCC is the same as a logic high.

It appears that active = LED On. If you put 5V on MF+ and ground MF- is should disable the stepper.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhfR5C.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Note that if you connected 24V backwards, you may have damaged the opto LED.